# If $D^1\cup_f D^1=S^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $f\colon S^0\to S^0$, so we can form the attaching space $D^1\cup_f D^1$. Is my intuition correct that this space is just $S^1$? Since $S^0=\{1,-1\}$, $f$ is either the identity, or swaps the points. If it's the identity, then I think it's clear that we have $S^1$. If $f$ swaps the points, then the copies of $D^1=[-1,1]$ are attached at opposite points, but I think after you untangle them, it's still $S^1$.

Comment: At least if you require $f$ to be a homeomorphism. If not you could take the constant map and the result would be something like -O . If $f$ is a homeomorphism, the result is a very elementary example of a 'twisted sphere'. These are homeomorphic to the standard sphere in all dimensions. (Since there are not always diffeomorphic to the sphere, they provide examples for so called exotic spheres and are interesting nevertheless.)

Comment: You failed to consider the case that $f : S^0 \to S^0$ is a constant map, in which case the attaching space is not $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get the circle either way. A way to confirm this formally is to write down a homeomorphism between the results of "normal" and "twisted" gluing. The homeomorphism is the identity on the first copy of $D^1$, and $x\mapsto -x$ on the second copy.